# Resource route in ruby and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, helper

I have

```
resources :blog
```

declared in my `routes.rb` file but when I try to access `blog_path` in a controller or a `html.erb` file, I get the following error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"blog", :action=>"show"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

I have created a controller called `BlogController` and defined the method `show` with a `show.html.erb` file in the views directory. If I define:

`match '/blog', to: 'blog#show', via: 'get'` instead, then `blog_path` works fine.

My understanding is resources: `blog` is just syntactic sugar for `match '/blog', to: 'blog#show', via: 'get'` and a bunch of other routes. Please help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`blog_path` is for generating path to a blog, so you need `id` or a blog object, this helper generates path like `/blogs/12` to `blogs#show`, and `blogs#show` is for showing an object. `blogs_path` generates `/blogs` to `blogs#index` (like to all blogs).

Look at [2 Resource Routing: the Rails Default](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

```
resources :photos

GET        /photos           index    display a list of all photos
GET        /photos/new       new      return an HTML form for creating a new photo
POST       /photos           create   create a new photo
GET        /photos/:id       show     display a specific photo
GET        /photos/:id/edit  edit     return an HTML form for editing a photo
PATCH/PUT  /photos/:id       update   update a specific photo
DELETE     /photos/:id       destroy  delete a specific photo
```

You have used `resources :blog` without `s`. It generates

```
            blog_index GET    /blog(.:format)                                          blog#index
                       POST   /blog(.:format)                                          blog#create
              new_blog GET    /blog/new(.:format)                                      blog#new
             edit_blog GET    /blog/:id/edit(.:format)                                 blog#edit
                  blog GET    /blog/:id(.:format)                                      blog#show
                       PUT    /blog/:id(.:format)                                      blog#update
                       DELETE /blog/:id(.:format)                                      blog#destroy
```

Comment: does this mean that all resources must end with an 's'? Like resources: photos, resources: blogs

Answer (score 5):

Make resource plural like this
resource :blogs

And make controller name blogs_controller.rb and its class name BlogsController

This is rails standard

Answer (score 0):

I'm recently starting to use Rails, but I noticed that when Rails generates a controller for me, it names it with an underscore between the name and the word controller.

Something like `blog_controller.rb`. A few days ago I replaced one with other without the underscore and get a similar error, not sure why.